# Convert True/False to 1/0 Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dummy-variable

I have a lot of dummy variables (T/F) that I want to convert to 1/0 with a function, I've tried the one below but it is not working...thanks for your help!

```
def function_country(row):
    if row == 'True':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

df2.apply(function_country,axis=1)

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: Use `df = df.astype(int)`

Comment: thanks for you suggestion, I've just tried, but I'm getting this error: ValueError: Wrong number of dimensions

Comment: it is fine now, thanks!

Comment: There are all boolean columns in dataframe ?

Comment: Because if not, is possible first filtr only `boolean` columns - `cols = df.select_dtypes(bool).columns` 
`df[cols] = df[cols].astype(int)`

Comment: Or `m = df.dtypes == 'bool'` 
`df.loc[:, m] = df.loc[:, m] .astype(int)`